# Find mean within data.fame

Tags: r, dataframe, mean

I have this table:

```
3702    GO:0009611  0.682
3711    GO:0009611  35.418
4081    GO:0009611  18.072
3702    GO:0033554  0.400
3702    GO:0006812  0.378
3702    GO:0006412  0.373
3702    GO:0009058  0.346
3702    GO:0051641  0.312
29760   GO:0009611  28.697
```

I don't care about first column. Column 2 has some values repeated. What I'd like to get is a `data.frame` where the first column is a value of the column 2 of my initial table, and the second column of my output would be the corresponding mean of the column 3 of my initial table.

Something like:

```
GO:0051179  1.7398
GO:0016311  2.1595
GO:0010467  1.45633
GO:0044093  15.483
GO:0006811  2.4175
GO:0044238  0.927667
GO:0006812  3.0138
GO:0006807  1.048
```

In fact, I've got this output using awk:

```
awk '{print $2"\t"$3}' BP.txt | awk '{hash1[$1]+=$2} ; {hash2[$1]+=1} END {for (x in hash1) {print x"\t"hash1[x]/hash2[x]}}'
```

but no clue about doing this in **R**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `tapply`. So if you had a data frame `dd`,  with three columns `V1`, `V2` and `V3`, then

```
tapply(dd$V3, dd$V2, mean)
```

would give you what you want.

Answer (score 3):

you could use `data.table`. If `df` is your data.frame, then do as following

```
library(data.table) ## 1.9.2+
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt <- dt[, list(col = mean(col3)), by = col2]
```

Comment: `Manoj`. list(col=mean(col3))- closing brace

Answer (score 2):

An alternative for the `tapply` from @csgillespie is the `by` function:

```
by(dd$V3, dd$V2, mean)
```

Answer (score 1):

or Just the good old `aggregate` (assuming `temp` is your data set)

```
aggregate(V3 ~ V2, temp, mean)
```